# Top.gg vote webhook (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a top.gg vote webhook, for some reason it gives me 'undefined' back when I vote on it. Here is my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send(`This is not a website!`);
});

app.post('/dblwebhook', function(req, res) {
    if(req.headers.authorization !== 'top.gg auth') return console.log(`Invalid request!`);
    if(req.body.type === 'test'){
        console.log(req.vote); //gives back 'undefined'
    } else {
        console.log(req.vote); //gives back 'undefined'
    }

   res.send({code: 'success'});
});
```

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, forgot to add the webhook midleware from the @topgg/sdk package. It makes it look like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const topgg = require('@topgg/sdk');

const webhook = new topgg.Webhook('auth');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send(`This is not a website!`);
});

app.post('/dblwebhook', webhook.middleware(), function(req, res) {
    if(req.headers.authorization !== 'top.gg auth') return console.log(`Invalid request!`);
    if(req.body.type === 'test'){
         console.log(req.vote);
    } else {
         console.log(req.vote);
    }

   res.send({code: 'success'});
});
```